# Log user settings in VSTO add-in

Tags: vsto

Is there any way to store client settings locally from a plugin utilization to another?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332568/vsto-outlook-addin-need-to-save-settings-best-way

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you want the settings to **roam** with the user (*shared settings regardless of machine*) or be **machine-dependent** (*vary machine to machine*). See [this related SO post which describes numerous ways for Outlook storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175091/175679).

If you are not using Outlook, you [can always leverage the `.settings` file as shared by Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332568/vsto-outlook-addin-need-to-save-settings-best-way).